# How do I close a form when a user clicks outside the form's window?

Tags: c#, forms, click

I want to close a System.Windows.Forms.Form if the user clicks anywhere outside it.  I've tried using IMessageFilter, but even then none of the messages are passed to PreFilterMessage.  How do I receive clicks outside a form's window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With thanks to [p-daddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36388/p-daddy) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298626/what-do-these-wndproc-codes-mean), I've found this solution which allows me to use ShowDialog:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    this.Capture = true;
}

protected override void OnCaptureChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Capture)
    {
        if (!this.RectangleToScreen(this.DisplayRectangle).Contains(Cursor.Position))
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Capture = true;
        }
    }

    base.OnCaptureChanged(e);
}
```

Comment: mm... It's not working as expected after all - when the form loads, I have the "hand" mouse cursor, and any click outside the form closes it. If I want to interact with the form itself, the first click only seems to clear the "Capture", and does not register inside the form (clicking on a checkbox does not check it, for example), and afterwards clicking outside does not close the window.
Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: @Noam: how simple is your form?  If it's just got one child, you could set the child's capture rather than the form's.

Comment: It's OnMouseCaptureChanged not OnCaptureChanged

Comment: I used OnVisibleChanged and OnMouseCaptreChanged and it works but some times the mouse is hidden.

Answer (score 11):

In your form's Deactivate event, put "this.Close()".  Your form will close as soon as you click anywhere else in Windows.

Update: I think what you have right now is a Volume button, and inside the Click event you create an instance of your VolumeSlider form and make it appear by calling ShowDialog() which blocks until the user closes the popped-up form.  In the next line you read the volume the user selected and use it in your program.

This is OK, but as you've noticed it forces the user to explicitly close the popup in order to get back to the main program.  Show() is the method you really want to use here on your popup form, but Show() doesn't block which means the Click event back on your main form finishes without knowing what the new volume is supposed to be.

A simple solution is to create a public method on your main form like this:

```
public void SetVolume(int volume)
{
    // do something with the volume - whatever you did before with it
}
```

Then, in your Volume button's Click event (also on the main form), you make the VolumeSlider appear like so:

```
VolumeSlider slider = new VolumeSlider();
slider.Show(this); // the "this" is needed for the next step
```

In the VolumeSlider form, as the user works the (I guess) scrollbar, you put this code in the scrollbar's ValueChanged event (I think that's what it is):

```
MainForm owner = (MainForm)this.Owner;
owner.SetVolume(scrollbar.Value);
```

And then in the VolumeSlider form's Deactivate event you would put this.Close() as mentioned above.  Your form will then behave as expected.

Comment: Me: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." Doctor: "Don't do that." See my updates above in a second.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you. I hate to be snarky and wrong at the same time.  :)

Comment: @JesonPark: sure it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate.aspx

Comment: tnx MusiGenesis i find it!

Answer (score 4):

With Simon's solution I had the same Problem describt by Noam. With following code I've avoid the "Click through" problem...

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{    
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    // if click outside dialog -> Close Dlg
    if (m.Msg == NativeConstants.WM_NCACTIVATE) //0x86
    {
        if (this.Visible)
        {
            if (!this.RectangleToScreen(this.DisplayRectangle).Contains(Cursor.Position))
                this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some context on this answer to enable someone to use it properly?

Comment: This is the truly correct answer. When you click outside of a form that was opened with `ShowDialog()`, 3 messages are sent: [`WM_NCACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632633(v=vs.85).aspx), [`WM_ACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646274(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`WM_ACTIVATEAPP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632614(v=vs.85).aspx). Don't use the 3rd one but the 2nd (**`WM_ACTIVATE`**) might be even better than the 1st one. Also don't forget to set `DialogResult`!

Answer (score 1):

You should use **Deactivate**: 
I have a form called **Form2**. 
In the **Deactivate** section of the **Properties** window. 
You declare the name **Form2_Deactivate**. 
In the **Form2.cs** file:

```
private void Form2_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a child form in an MDI application, you could trap the click in the parent form, otherwise the solution will be messy.

I am not convinced what you suggest represents intuitive UI behaviour anyway. Are you sure that is the best design?

Comment: it's a volume slider - that seems to be the way everyone else has implemented them.

Comment: This isn't too different from a drop-down box - the choice list goes away as soon as you click somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a popup window that behaves a little bit like a menu, except that it lets you interact with your controls, you could try hosting a usercontrol inside a toolstrip dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLY WAY :
on Form1 use this code to call form2:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click
    Form2.Owner = Me
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

and then use this code on form1 again :

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    If Form2.IsHandleCreated = True Then
        Form2.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simple :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f = new Form();
        f.LostFocus +=new EventHandler(f_LostFocus);
        f.Show();
    }

    void f_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f = sender as Form;
        f.Close();
        f.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: This is what worked for me!
Other solutions are just clunky, especially the one using OnDeactivate() that makes my entire application give focus to an entirely other application when closing the child form, for some reason (??)...