# How can I close a Form (ShowDialog) when the user clicks outside of the form?

Tags: .net, winforms, mouseevent

I have a Form and it contains a TreeView. How can I get a message when the mouse is clisked outside of the form (so I can close it)? I tried CaptureMouse but that stopped the mouse from working inside the tree. And I did not get the MouseDown message when I clicked outside the form.

I cannot use the WndProc check for WM_NCACTIVATE because I am displaying this from inside an Excel AddIn and somehow Excel stops this message from being sent if the click is over Excel.

The other solutions in [How do I ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298491/how-do-i-close-a-form-when-a-user-clicks-outside-the-forms-window) don't work. I tried and from the comments others have tried too - and they don't work (including the answer marked as an answer).

thanks - dave

Comment: One solution would be to use a non-modal window, which would (should) let you respond to the deactivate event. But then you'll have to make the window send notification to the owner when it closes, rather than depending on the `ShowDialog` behavior.

Comment: The only other option you got is a low-level mouse hook, set by SetWindowsHookEx() so you can see the mouse down before it gets dispatched to the window that is clicked.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx  Needs work if you do this in .NET 4.0 and up.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example for you to test because I don't have any excel plugin code to work with.

My idea is to work with a timer to check if any of your form control has the focus.
If none has the focus then close the form.

First declare a Timer in your form, set its interval to 1 second (or less) and add this code

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Focused == true) return;
    if (AnyFocused(this) == false)
    {
        this.timer1.Stop();
        this.Close();
        // Application.Exit(); -- not recommended but...
    }
}

private bool AnyFocused(Control c)
{
    if (c.Focused == true) return true;
    foreach (Control x in c.Controls)
    {
        if (x.Focused == true) return true;
        if (x.Controls != null && x.Controls.Count > 0)
            return AnyFocused(x);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have made a little test with a simple winform application and it works, but your condition (Excel Plugin) could be very different. Let me know.